# Talking about school grades

Tags: phrase-usage

It turns out it’s quite hard to find anything on marks/grades at school on the Net.
I have a few questions I’ll be happy to find answers to:
In the USA the grading system is from A to F, you can easily say “get a D”, or “I got a few D’s”.

1. What about other grading systems like in Russia, for example, from 5 to 1.
   Should I say **“I got four for history today”** or **“I got A four for history today”.**
2. Can I say: **“I got two fours today”?**

Comment: Assuming everyone in Russia knows that grades there are *numbers* rather than *letters*, AND assuming your context is one where all the addressees know English reasonably well, you can reasonably talk about getting a 2 or a 4, for example. But unless the context makes it screamingly obvious what you're talking about, I think it would only be sensible to refer to ***grade D*** or ***grade 4***. In which case you'd normally be expected to precede that by a indefinite article (but it's not *required*, whether or not you include a meaningful noun before the letter/digit).

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica - Saying "grade 4" would be a bit confusing in Canada, where that is the equivalent of "4th grade" in the US.  You'd have to say "a grade **of** 4" to remove the ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

It might help to have some context:

There are also numeric scores in the US. Each test or assignment has a maximum number of points you can earn. For example, a small quiz might be out of 5 points (so your score would range from 0-5). All of these points are averaged into a final grade and this number is translated into a letter grade, where an A might be scores between 91 and 100 (which are percents even if they aren’t always labeled as such). The exact range for each letter varies from school to school. You can also figure out a letter grade for each assignment in the same way.

There are also, rarely, some tests in the US that grade on a scale of 5-1, where 5 is the best and 1 is the worst. The Advanced Placement exams (which are taken in high school and if you score high enough it counts as college credit) are like that.

**To answer the question**, number grades, much like letter grades, are countable, so it’s correct to say:

- I got **a 5** on the AP exam
- I got **two 100s** today

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I think the correct preposition to use when specifying the subject is 'in'. For example:

> I got a B **in** history.

As for differences in grading systems, the general rule above should apply (determiner+grade name). For example, "I got one Four and two Threes in my exams". If you want to be very clear with grade names like 'Four', 'Excellent' or 'Distinction', you could just use the format `an/an X grade`. For example, 'a Distinction grade', or 'a Three grade'.

Comment: The wired thing is that Macmillan says that “for” is also possible: She got top marks for history (it’s the example from the dictionary). Thanks for your comment!

Comment: @Checkit Please provide a link to that dictionary page.

Comment: @EddieKal https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/mark_1#mark_1__8

Comment: @Checkit I suppose it's possible but "for+subject name" sounds a little strange to me. "an A in history" sounds more natural than "an A for history" in my opinion. On the other hand, abstract nouns with 'for' sound ok, e.g. "You get an A for effort, but you still lost.".

Comment: @kandyman I agree with you, actually. It’s just I had read this example right before I posted my question, so I simply copied the preposition))

Comment: You got a D *in* History, but a D *on* a history test.

Comment: @StephenS you get an A for observation!